# Using international database on Google Books API

Tags: server, google-api, google-books

I've tested the Google Books API now with servers in a few different countries (Germany, UK, Netherlands; it should be in Europe) and realized that the results depend heavily on the request's origin region. For some German books (I search by ISBN) I get 20 or 30 results using the German server but nothing on the others and vice versa.

Is there any way to access the complete database Google has to offer? Note that I'm not trying to access anything like text excerpts or other critical content in terms of licensing. I only need the general information like Title, Authors, ISBN, ...

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I found a paragraph in the documentation under "Using the API" (for Google books) that might explain it:

"Setting User Location:

Google Books respects copyright, contract, and other legal restrictions associated with the end user's location. As a result, some users might not be able to access book content from certain countries. For example, certain books are "previewable" only in the United States; we omit such preview links for users in other countries. Therefore, the API results are restricted based on your server or client application's IP address."

My workaround is to search while using a VPN - that returned the titles in English like I wanted to. If there's another way to solve it I'd gladly hear that too.

Comment: VPN is definitely an option if you’re interested in a specific region. I just needed as many relevant results as possible, so I went with an Azure server in the UK and use multiple services besides Google Books. I can recommend OpenLibrary, WorldCat and HathiTrust.